# Logic Alphabet for more than Two Variables

Tags: lo.logic, boolean-algebras

Is it possible to generalise Zellweger’s [logic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_alphabet) for more than two Boolean variables?

Can it be done by only using the 16 binary connectives?

Thanks.

Comment: You will presumably be forced to use 3d-letters for three variables :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when the number of Boolean variables is $n=3$, since the number of connectives is $2^{2^n}=(2^{2^2})^{n-1}$, we can use infix notation like $pxqyr$, where $p$, $q$, $r$ are Boolean variables and $x$, $y$ are among the 16 symbols. The interpretation is that if $p$ is true then the value is $qxr$, otherwise $qyr$.

In general $2^{2^n}$ is probably too big for any compact notation to be possible.

Comment: Of course every Boolean function can be expressed using just 1 symbol, the Sheffer stroke, but I assume you're not asking about that.